# SQL Server table keeps locking on inserts & updates, has around 60k rows and 130 columns (55 are computed). What to do to solve this problem?

Tags: sql-server, performance, locking

The table is used very frequently for read operations but due to it being updated every 5 minutes it keeps locking up off and on.

Are there any alternative strategies or databases that can be used to solve the read locking issues?

Comment: replicate the data so that all read only get the replicated data, alo i doubt that such big tables are really good, the comuted columns could reside in another table which get inserted updated and deleted by triggers

Comment: You need to show the query(s) and the table definitions with indexes; SQL server will use appropriate indexes to locate rows to update so if you are missing a suitable index it will be taking page or table locks, assuming your update isn't trying to touch every row or majority of rows anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Read the table with a row-versioning isolation level to prevent writers from blocking readers, or readers from blocking writers.  See [Transaction locking and row versioning guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver16).